# Show field value if it isn't nil in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a large multistep form that builds a single object step by step using [Wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked). As I've been testing the form, I notice when I hit the back button on the form (the one I provide to go back to the previous step), the values in radio buttons and in select fields are set back to the default option. The text fields show the text that the user entered in. I would like to show the field value to the user if they entered data into the field.

I have figured out how to do this with a long if statement in my view, but would like to simplify it.

```
<% if @business.business_entity_type.nil? %>
    <%= f.select :business_entity_type, options_for_select([["Structure", "0"], ["Sole Proprietorship", "Sole Proprietorship"], ["Partnership", "Partnership"], ["Corporation", "Corporation"]], selected: "0", disabled: "0") %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.select :business_entity_type, options_for_select([["Structure", "0"], ["Sole Proprietorship", "Sole Proprietorship"], ["Partnership", "Partnership"], ["Corporation", "Corporation"]], disabled: "0"), :value => @business.business_entity_type %>
<% end %>
```

When I put this in ternary format I get a syntax error.

```
<%= f.select :business_entity_type, options_for_select([["Structure", "0"], ["Sole Proprietorship", "Sole Proprietorship"], ["Partnership", "Partnership"], ["Corporation", "Corporation"]], <%= @business.business_entity_type.nil? ? selected: "0" : :value => @business.business_entity_type %>, disabled: "0") %>
```

When I embed an if statement inside the field I get a syntax error as well.

```
<%= f.select :business_entity_type, options_for_select([["Structure", "0"], ["Sole Proprietorship", "Sole Proprietorship"], ["Partnership", "Partnership"], ["Corporation", "Corporation"]], disabled: "0", selected: "0"), :value => @business.business_entity_type if @business.business_entity_type.present? %>
```

How would I achieve the same objective with more clean code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured instead of using :value I could just use selected:

```
<%= f.select :business_entity_type, options_for_select([["Structure", "0"], ["Sole Proprietorship", "Sole Proprietorship"], ["Partnership", "Partnership"], ["Corporation", "Corporation"]], disabled: "0", selected: ( @business.business_entity_type.nil? ? "0" : @business.business_entity_type)) %>
```